# Can I directly pass a label for a named route to<router-link>?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Say in my `router.js` I have something like this:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    label: 'Start',
    component: Home
  }
]
```

Then where I render my router link, I'd like to be able to use the alternate label property declared above, instead of manually entering it, and to avoid defining it somewhere else. I tried the bit below but it does not work (it works for the 'path' property though)

```js
<router-link :to="{name: 'home'}">{{ this.$router.label }}</router-link>
```

EDIT: I found that (obviously!) `this.$router` refers to the current, active route.

Answer (score 0):

For now at least, this is my solution:

- In `router.js` (or `/router/index.js` in my case) declare the routes with labels as indicated in the original question. And export *both* the routes and the router object.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    label: 'Start',
    component: Home
  }
  ...
] 

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export { router as default, routes };
```

- In `main.js` import both variables and store `routes` in a way you can retrieve them anywhere.

```js
import router, { routes } from '@/router'
Vue.prototype.routes = routes

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

- Where you want to "render" the route links (in my case a navbar layout), do this (using vuetify here):

```js
  <v-app-bar app color="secondary" dark>        
     <v-btn v-for="route in routes" :to="{name: route.name}" key='route.name' text rounded :exact="true">
            {{ route.label }}
     </v-btn>        
  </v-app-bar>
```

I'm sure this can be improved probably using Vuex (which I'm still studying about).

**UPDATE**
Found a much better solution, that don't require the `routes` export/import and its assignment to `Vue.prototype.routes = routes`. Simply do this in the component where you want to use the routes data with labels and all. The template piece (`v-btn` etc) remains the same.

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'LayoutNav',  
  data() {
    return {      
      routes: this.$router.options.routes
    };
  }
};
</script>
```